# Cross compiling with Clang - `crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory`

Tags: c, linux, linker, clang, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile a C file to an aarch64 ELF on x86 linux. I've set up a cross build environment on Gentoo but when I run the following command:

```
clang -target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu --sysroot=/usr/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/ input.c -I /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/11.3.0/ -L /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/11.3.0/
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory
```

However, in the directory `/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/11.3.0/`, there is a file called `crtbeginS.o`. My question then is what additional compiler flags am I missing to get the linker to find this file?

Comment: Is it 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: `crtbeginS.o` is a 64-bit elf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

clang doesn't seem to pick up these 2 files in particular from their original location, even if you point to them explicitly. You can instead copy or symlink the files in a directory that will cause them to be picked up, like the `$SYSROOT/usr/lib/` directory. Adjusting for the paths in your post:

```
  ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/11.3.0/crtbeginS.o /usr/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/usr/lib/crtbeginS.o
  ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/11.3.0/crtendS.o /usr/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/usr/lib/crtendS.o
```

(this was tested with clang-16.0.1)

Comment: Ah, yea I figured this out but thanks for sharing the solution for others!